# Starting something with a JButton and pausing it with the same JButton

Tags: java, multithreading, jbutton

I'm not sure how to do it but I want my JButton to start running a method when it is pressed and then pause that method when I click it again. Also, the method should run continuously.
Right now, my button does not pause and start and it does not run continuously either.

```
private JButton playButton = new JButton("Play!");
playButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
     ?????
}
```

I know the answer to my problem goes in there but my attempts have just ended in an unbreakable while loop.

I asked somebody else and I was told I would have to run something in a separate thread. Problem is, I don't know anything about threads. Is there any other way to do it without threads?

Comment: If it is a long running task then you would have to use a thread and in this case it is.

Comment: Use [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) and take a quick look at the appropriate [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)

Answer (score 0):

Implementing a function/method that runs continuously until told by an external signal to stop...is hard to do without threads. Event handlers of GUI elements, by nature, run on separate threads with the application logic because if the two run synchronously (i.e. a button control waits for some processing to be done before being able to accept a click event once more) ... such application would suck. True story bro.

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean running = false;
private JButton playButton = new JButton("Play!");
Thread stuff = new Thread(new RunningThread());
playButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    if (!running) {
        stuff.start();
        running = true;
    }
    else {
        if (stuff.isAlive()) {
            stuff.stop();
        }
        running = false;
    }

} 

public class RunningThread implements Runnable {

    public RunningThread() {
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //DO STUFF: You also want a way to tell that you are finished and that the next button press should start it up again, so at the end make a function like imDone() that sends a message to your page that changes running = false;
    }

}
```

Something like this should work. The only problem is this is stop rather than a pause. A pause would be a little more tricky and dependent on what exactly is happening inside the function.